# Why I get different result when try Suzuki Abe border following method?

Tags: algorithm, notation

In the [paper](http://tpf-robotica.googlecode.com/svn-history/r397/trunk/Vision/papers) by Suzuki Abe, I try the border following algorithm from their example:[image: Exampe in the paper],

and here the algorithm:
[image: Algorithm1]
[image: Algorithm2]

My result from their algorithm is [image: Result]

It's different from the paper result, the result become -2 when in paper 2, when I process step 3.4 part a. Is it (i<sub>3</sub>,j<sub>3</sub>+1) mean coordinate column from current pixel+1?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your implementation, it's hard to know for sure. But, my first guess is that, in your code, you're deciding to label a pixel as -LNBD only if [image] is zero, instead of also confirming that this cell was examined your implementation of step (3.3). So, in your loop that implements (3.3), add a flag that flips to true when your counterclockwise search for a 1-pixel value hits [image], and then modify your implementation of step (3.4(a)) to also check this flag.

I encountered the same problem myself and didn't quite realize it until I read the proof of Lemma 2 on P 43.

Comment: I have no idea why it won't accept my MathJax inline expressions!  What am I doing wrong??